# Irish Residency

Tags: uk, ireland, residency

Two questions, does Irish residency give you permission to travel to mainland Europe without needing a visa? Secondly does the Irish residency give you access to the United Kingdom in terms of tourism or in case you want to purchase a vacation home?

Comment: Where in mainland Europe specifically? Requiring a visa to enter the UK depends on your nationality. You can use the UK Government website https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y to see if you need a visa, it will ask you questions and tell you if you need one.

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this as off-topic. The asker wants to make a short-term visit to another country. That's exactly what our site is about.

Answer (score 6):

Irish residence permission does *not* give you extra abilities to travel through Europe. Visa requirements will still be based on your passport nationality. While the UK allows holders of some Irish visas to enter the UK without an additional UK visa, this does not currently apply to Irish work/study visas.